# Implement Add method in generic class inherited from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, ienumerable

Having the class as following

```
public class MyGeneric<T> : IEnumerable
{
    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        this.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetNullItems()
    {
        foreach (T item in this)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I instantiate an object of type *MyGeneric* and add items to it I get a `System.StackOverflowException`

```
MyGeneric<int?> mylist = new MyGeneric<int?>()
{
    1,null,3,null,5,6,7,null,9,10
};
```

The problem is that when I add **1** the `Add` method is called, and inside `Add` method the code snippet `this.Add(item);` means call `Add` again, whereas I meant to add the item to the collection.

If I delete the `Add` method I get a ***'MyClass.MyGeneric' does not contain a definition for 'Add'*** error.

I'm confused, how should I add the item?

Comment: Think about *where* you want to add item and solution will come

Comment: What collection did you intend to add it to?  There is no collection in your example.

Comment: I wanted the class object itself to be a collection, correct me if I wrote the class wrong.

Comment: Your class currently doesn't have any fields. Where do you expect it to store information?

Comment: I want my class to be a list or something, I thought inheriting from IEnumerable is enough.

Comment: I got it, I should have inherited from `List<T>` not from `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari, perhaps -- though why are you creating your own collection at all?  Do you intend for it to behave differently than a list?

Comment: @KirkWoll I wanted similar behavior like `List` but did not want to use extension because I want it as a separate class so that the new methods do not exists on every `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sure.

```
public void Add(T item)
{
    this.Add(item);
}
```

Here you have a method that calls itself, which in turn calls itself, which in turn calls itself, until you run out of stack.

You probably want to add a field of type `List<T>`, and have your `Add` method call `_list.Add(item);`. Or write the new item to disk, or store it wherever else you want -- but a list would be the most common place to store it.

Comment: One might even say this question is perfect for StackOverflow;-)